# Android Map Markers add with Animation

Tags: android, google-maps, animation, google-maps-markers

normally I am adding markers like this:

```
Marker Pino = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(mKonum)
                                .title(misim)
                                .draggable(true)
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
                                .snippet(mTarih.toString()));
```

but I saw at [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/) very cool animation while adding markers with drop dawn animation or bouncing at the part of

> Custom Markers and Info windows

[image]

how can success this animation in my app

Comment: Look this.....https://gist.github.com/imminent/9183e661536914c7ff58

Comment: No, it dont works

Comment: What happen Any Error?

Comment: Sorry Sachin, after some try it works. Thanks too much

Comment: did you got solution of above problem ? if yes please post answer Thanks

@mehmet

Comment: @PradeepBishnoi yes. the Sach answer is enough for me.